aggregation based upon multiple criteria and time range (R)
Ultimately, I want to aggregate the amount column in my data over modular groups that do not yet exist but that are the composite of two existing groups and a time difference dimension.
I have a dataset that is structured like this:
data <- tibble(
  date = as.POSIXct(c('2023-07-01 12:00:00', '2023-07-01 13:00:00', '2023-07-02 12:00:00',  
                      '2023-07-03 14:00:00', '2023-07-03 16:00:00', '2023-07-04 12:00:00', '2023-07-04 14:00:00', 
                      '2023-07-05 10:00:00', '2023-07-05 12:00:00')),
  transaction_id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  seller_ID = c(201, 202, 201, 201, 204, 205, 206, 201, 207),
  amount = c(100, 150, 200, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550),
)

I want to add to this a time difference, which is the duration between the occurrence of a seller_ID and its previous occurrence.
ordered_data <- data %>%
  group_by(seller_ID) %>%
  arrange(seller_ID, date) %>%
  mutate(time_diff_hours = as.numeric(difftime(date, lag(date, default = first(date)), units = "hours"))) %>%
  ungroup()

Conceptually, there are a few next steps (and this is where I am struggling):
First, I want to group together all transactionIDs regardless of seller_IDs (so all transaction_ID 1 rows should be aggregated together). BUT, I also want to include in this aggregation repeated sellerIDs if those sellerIDs appear within 24 hours (inclusive) of the previous (lag) appearance of that sellerID. So in the example data, all transactionID 1s get aggregated together by transactionID, but tranactionID2 which includes sellerID 201 is also included in the aggregation because it happened within 24s of the first appearance of sellerID 201, who was a part to transactionID1. In other words, simply aggregating by transactionID would not be sufficient.
However, I also don't want to include sellerIDs in an aggregation if they happen too far from the previous appearance. For example, the two other instances of sellerID 201 (transactionIDs 3 and 5) are not counted with transaction ID 1 because they happen too long (>24 hours) afterward the previous appearance of sellerID 201 and are not lumped together either for the same reason.
In short, I have groups, transactionID and sellerID, but I want to sometimes combine transactionIDs together based on the temporal relationship between sellerIDs.
The ideal groups would look like this:
ordered_data <- ordered_data  %>%
  mutate(ideal_groups = c(1,1,2,3,1,2,4,4,3))


Why do rows 5 and 6 also have group 1 and 2? They have different transaction_id and seller_ID.

Andre, you are correct. I had an old version of the data stored when I wrote the example. The amended data and data_with_ideal_groups should be correct.

Can you please check again that the output matches the description and the input? It doesn't make sense to me and I suspect there's still an inconsistency.

@JonSpring, I am pretty sure it is correct as amended. All transaction_IDS are clustered together and sellerIDs cluster together if they are separated by 24 hours or less worth of time. So in the toy data, transactionID 1 and transactionID two should cluster, because the sellerID is common and seen within 24 hours of each other.

Can you please describe the logic why row 5 with seller 204 and transaction ID 3 is part of group 1? (Same as original comment question.)

@JonSpring, I see where the confusion was coming from I think. I had applied the groups to the arranged data, not the raw data. I amended the example to make this clearer. You are correct that row 5 in the initial data does not go to group 1. Row 5 in the arranged data has transaction ID1 and seller ID 202

ordered_data |> 
    mutate(groups = ifelse(!is.na(lag(date)) & date - lag(date) <= hours(24), lag(transaction_id), transaction_id), .by = seller_ID)|>
    mutate(groups = match(groups, unique(groups)))

Output:
# A tibble: 9 × 7
  date                transaction_id seller_ID amount time_diff_hours
  <dttm>                       <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2023-07-01 12:00:00              1       201    100               0
2 2023-07-02 12:00:00              2       201    200              24
3 2023-07-03 14:00:00              3       201    300              26
4 2023-07-05 10:00:00              5       201    500              44
5 2023-07-01 13:00:00              1       202    150               0
6 2023-07-03 16:00:00              3       204    350               0
7 2023-07-04 12:00:00              4       205    400               0
8 2023-07-04 14:00:00              4       206    450               0
9 2023-07-05 12:00:00              5       207    550               0
  ideal_groups groups
         <dbl>  <int>
1            1      1
2            1      1
3            2      2
4            3      3
5            1      1
6            2      2
7            4      4
8            4      4
9            3      3

